# Tf.data.Dataset store a array column Error

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensor

Is there any way to store inside a tf.data.Dataset formed from a pandas dataframe, a column where each cell corresponds to an array of floats?

I have a pandas dataframe where a column has a list of floats for each row, and I transform it to a tf.data.Dataset in the following way to send it to a Tensorflow model:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe)))
```

But I can't store the array column, is there any way to do it?

> ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).